# Drupal multiple steps way to add an article

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I would like the member/visitor of my website to be able to create article about themselves. Instead of using the normal way which is "Content - Add Custom Article" and fill up everything in the lengthy way. I prefer to let them do it in a multiple steps way (just like check-out process in Amazon).

i would like to create a multiple steps form that consists of 3 steps to create a content page. The first step needs to be able to allow users to upload multiple images in 1 shot and display the thumbnails in a gallery below it. The gallery needs to allow re-arrangement(re-ordering), cropping and resizing.

The layout is something like this

#

Step 1 of 3 - Tell us about your detail

Name : 
Your Photos :

Next Step

#

Please give some suggestion on the modules that I can use to achieve this kind of design.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.agentic.ca/blog/fully-manageable-image-slideshow-your-home-page-drupal)  might be useful. 
 [Media gallery](https://drupal.org/project/media_gallery)  module also might be useful though it is still in beta. 
As for the multistep process for saving articles, it seems to be pretty straightforward way of storing the information as user goes from one step to another and saving the entity when the final step is complete.

Comment: Thanks! the article seems impressive! Is there any step by step tutorial for me to start building a multistep process? I am stuck. What i can find a a lot of PHP codes (MForm, Ctools form wizard) which i don't understand unfortunately.

Comment: I would suggest you look at building a simple form on your own first, the multistep form would extend from that.  Here (http://davidsonj.com/blog/how-create-multi-step-form-drupal-7) is some actual code to get you started

Comment: Just found out multiple Image Upload widget https://drupal.org/project/multiupload_imagefield_widget and ManualCrop https://drupal.org/project/manualcrop worked for me!

Comment: Just manage to get Multistep up. It is really much easier. https://drupal.org/project/multistep